# Add dpkg .symbols or.shlibs to package made using checkinstall

Tags: debian, package-management, dpkg, checkinstall

I have created a simple package using `checkinstall` of the Oracle Instantclient client libraries, the package installs without problem and is seen in the system.

Problem is, that `checkinstall` doesn't create `/var/lib/dpkg/info/oracle-instantclient11.2-basic.symbols` or `/var/lib/dpkg/info/oracle-instantclient11.2-basic.shlibs` files so when I try to create another package (with proper build scripts) that depends on `oracle-instantclient11.2-basic` the build fails with

```
dpkg-shlibdeps: error: no dependency information found for \
 /usr/lib/libclntsh.so.11.1 (used by \
 debian/libopendbx1-oracle/usr/lib/opendbx/liboraclebackend.so.1.2.0).
dh_shlibdeps: dpkg-shlibdeps \
 -Tdebian/libopendbx1-oracle.substvars \
 debian/libopendbx1-oracle/usr/lib/opendbx/liboraclebackend.so.1.2.0 \
 returned exit code 2
make: *** [binary-arch] Error 9
```

Is there an easy way to automatically create a package with `.symbols` or `.shlibs` files?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem by creating `/var/lib/dpkg/info/oracle-instantclient11.2-basic.shlibs` with following contents:

```
libclntsh 11.1 oracle-instantclient11.2-basic (>=11)
```

That's obviously sub-optimal.